# Lucene java,Use span query to find hits per page

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, lucene

I am using lucene as Search engine. When we use the standardAnalyser,the stop words are filtered out. That means, when we search for a phrase that has stop words we can't find results for exact phrase.
Example we search for "This is a game" it looks for "This game". (I look at it to work this way)

I need to filter out stop words if someone is searching just for 'a' or 'the'etc (stop words), but not in phrase searches.

EDIT: Looks like it works with **QueryParser** Object.

However I cant get the results for hits per page in single document for phrase searches. I am looking to use SpanQuery for it, any ideas on how to use it?

Thanks,
Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filter stopwords, the relative place of the words is not modified. For example "this is a game" results in:
This at pos 0
game at pos 3

This way when you generate a phrase query (using the usual query parser) with the same stopwords it will work as expected.

Some artifacts may appear, however. The phrases
"this is a game"
"this is some game"

will both match equally well for the query "this is a game".

Regarding the SpanQuery... I don't quite understand the question.

Comment: I would like to find the number of hits per page, using span query object. Is that possible?